# What is the use of endpoint in sns.subscribe in case of sns fan-out events

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm working on a service that uses an SNS-SQS fanout model in Python. I understand that in order to send a notification to a specific SQS, I need to provide a filter policy. However, I'm confused about the need to provide an endpoint in the subscribe function if a notification within SNS goes to all the subscribed queues by default.
Can someone please explain this to me?

I went through the documentation but still confused.
Following is the code:

```py
def sns_to_sqs(self, queue_url):
        sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs')
        queue_attributes = sqs_client.get_queue_attributes(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            AttributeNames=['QueueArn']
        )
        sqs_queue_arn = queue_attributes['Attributes']['QueueArn']

        sf_filter_policy = {
            'name': ['abc']
        }

        response = self.sns_client.subscribe(
            TopicArn=self.topic_arn,
            Protocol='sns',
            Endpoint=sqs_queue_arn,
            Attributes={
                'FilterPolicy': json.dumps(sf_filter_policy)
            }
        )

        aqui_filter_policy = {
            'name': ['pqr']
        }

        response = self.sns_client.subscribe(
            TopicArn=self.topic_arn,
            Protocol='sns',
            Endpoint=sqs_queue_arn,
            Attributes={
                'FilterPolicy': json.dumps(aqui_filter_policy)
            }
        )
```

In the above code I have added the filter policy and queues are subscribed to sns topic. But since, I have the filter policy in place then do I have a need to provide the subscription URL/ARN?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you show your code please? [`Subscribe`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) is not the same as [`Publish`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html), which is what you're mixing it up with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have added the code for reference.

Comment: Filter policies either [act](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) on the message attributes or on the message body - nothing to do with the endpoint. What is the actual question here? You've done the subscription. You now need to publish a message to the topic for it to be 'fanned out'. In your code, you also should have 2 SQS queues for a fanout as right now, you have 2 filter policies for 1 queue.